# ReactJS - Some element render only after a refresh (F5). Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, render

Here is what I mean:
https://i.gyazo.com/6c5cd185fe1437142ce19a231e4db3aa.mp4

I have an integration of the facebook like button plug-in. The problem is that it only renders if I press F5. How do I make it render by default?

The website is live here: http://shacrow.com

Thank you.

Comment: Initilize your `FB` plugin in `componentDidMount()` of `/featured` component

Comment: How do I initialize that? Sorry if it's very basic for you. I hope you can explain me.

Comment: <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://facebook.com/ShacrowDesign" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>

This is what is used to display the buttons.

Comment: And this is what is on the html file:
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=MY_APPID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked for more specific, do something like

```
componentDidMount(){
   window.FB.XFBML.parse(); //saying FB plugin to re parse the dom.
}
```

in your component containing

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="facebook.com/ShacrowDesign"; data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Since your `FB sdk` loads before your `like` button in html. so we are asking `FB sdk` to parse the page after `react component` rendered to the page.